# Subtract a list from every list in a list of lists

Tags: list-manipulation, vector, map

I have a list of lists such as:

```
{{a,b,c},{d,e,f},{g,h,i}}
```

Now need to subtract {x,y,z} from each list in the above list of list. such as:

```
{{a-x,b-y,c-z},{d-x,e-y,f-z},{g-x,h-y,i-z}}
```

I can do this using a For loop. Is there a better Functional way of doing this?

Comment: Use `Map` (it's shorthand notation: `/@`): `Subtract[#, {x, y, z}] & /@ {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, i}}`

Comment: # - {x, y, z} & /@ {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, i}}

Comment: Alternatively, `Transpose@lst - {x, y, z} // Transpose`.